# i have inserted textfield into table view through custom cell now how to get the data from the textview

Tags: iphone

hello  i am having table view and in that table view i have put text field on each cell, now how to get the data from the cell , data is in the textfield..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say it's a custom tableviewcell?  How did you make this custom cell?  You need to assign an IBOutlet to your textfield and access the text that way (using the 'text' property).

If it's not a custom cell but a standard UITableViewCell then you can get it's text using cell.textLabel.text.

If it's neither of the above then please provide further detail.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can search on attributes? GetRowCellValue() ?